# Script to check exe files version

Tags: scripting

I would like to know the version of all exe files in D: Drive (right click the exe, details tab, "Product version" field)

I have done a script which include sigcheck.exe from Sysinternals Suite; it finishes with a CSV file with all the exe files I include in the script, so, I have to put them manually.

The thing is, I want to do something to avoid writing the path of each exe files.

I tried with forfiles.exe /P D: /S /M *.exe but how can I get the results to be checked by the sigcheck.exe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a simple line in powershell, no need for external tools:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.exe" D: |select fullname,@{n="ProductVersion";e={$_.versioninfo.productversion}}
```

Result:

```
FullName                        ProductVersion
--------                        --------------
D:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe   18.06
D:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe 18.06
D:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe  18.06
```

Comment: It works if the exe file is the root of D: but it is not searching inside of the other directories.
Perhaps I thought in a complicated solution instead using only commands.

Thanks Gerald.

Comment: The parameter `-recurse` makes it search for all .exe files under the target directory, including subdirectories.

Comment: It took a long time to search all D: drive, that's why I thought it didn't work.

Thanks for your help Gerald.